# Trying to include a dynamic variable within JSON data of a Bash / Shell POST request to API endpoint

Tags: json, bash, api, shell, curl

I am trying to submit a POST request using Bash that includes JSON data with a variable equal to that of a random string. I get the string dynamically by parsing a file which can vary in content... and may contain regex characters and also new lines.

I will provide an example string here with a curl request that works successfully with the API I am posting this request to. I can only get the request to go through with the string  hardcoded into the JSON data and not while assigning a variable to the string like for instance **`stringVar`** and using the variable in the JSON data. I could sure use some help where I am messing this up

my working shell script looks something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_API_TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST 'https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint' -d '{
    "name": "my-project",
    "files": [
        {
            "data": "helloWorldFunction() {\n echo \"hello world\" \n}"
        },
    ],
}'
```

This works, however I need to change data's value from the string
**helloWorldFunction() {\n echo "hello world" \n}**
to a variable

I have tried settings the variable in different ways in the JSON content from reading suggestions on other questions. For instance I have tried tried changing my shell script to

```
#!/bin/bash

stringVar="helloWorldFunction() {\n echo \"hello world\" \n}"

curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_API_TOKEN>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST 'https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint' -d '{
    "name": "my-project",
    "files": [
        {
            "data": "${stringVar}"
        },
    ],
}'
```

i have tried setting the variable like this

"${stringVar}" | turns into ${stringVar}

"$stringVar" | turns into "$stringVar"

and

"'${stringVar}'"

"'$stringVar'"

both seem to return this error
`{"error":{"code":"bad_request","message":"Invalid JSON"}}curl: (3) unmatched brace in URL position 1: {\n`

and

stringVar

`stringVar`

$stringVar

"'"$stringVar"'"

""$stringVar""

${stringVar}

all seem to return this error
`{"error":{"code":"bad_request","message":"Invalid JSON"}}`

Ahh any help on what I am doing wrong would be great.
Thanks in advance y'all

Comment: Do not generate the JSON by hand. Use a tool like `jq` to generate it for you. *You* know what string you want the recipient to get after decoding the payload; the tool knows how to make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to interpolate the value of a variable, you need to enclose the string in double-quotes(`"`), but the JSON also requires literal double-quotes.

The easiest solution is probably to use a here-document to feed the data into `curl`'s standard input, as in @Gilles Quénot's answer. But you can still pass it in via the command line; you just have to be careful with the quotes.

This is one way:

```
curl ... -d '{
  "name": "my-project",
  "files": [
    {
        "data": "'"$stringVar"'"
    }
  ]
}'
```

The JSON here is mostly contained within single quotation marks (`'`...`'`). But right after opening the pair of literal `"`s that will enclose the value of `data`, we close the single quotes and switch our shell quotation mode to double quotes in order to include the value of `$stringVar`.  After closing the double quotes around that expansion, we go back into single quotes for the rest of the JSON, starting with closing the literal double-quotes around the value of `data`.

In a language that used `+` for string concatenation, it would look like `'... "data": "' + "$stringVar" + '"... '`, but in the shell you just put the strings next to each other with no operator to concatenate them.

As an alternative, you could put the whole thing in double-quotes, but then you need backslashes to include the literal double quotes that are part of the JSON:

```
curl ... -d "{
  \"name\": \"my-project\",
  \"files\": [
    {
      \"data\": \"$stringVar\"
    }
  ]
}"
```

So that requires a lot more changes if you're starting from plain JSON; it also looks messier, IMO.

You can also use a tool that knows how to build JSON and let it worry about quoting etc. Here's one way to build it with `jq`:

```
jq -n --arg data "$stringVar" '{ 
  "name": "my-project", 
  "files": [ 
    { 
      "data": $data 
    } 
  ] 
}'
```

Using `--arg` creates a variable inside `jq` – I named it `data` – which can then be included in an expression with the syntax `$varname` (`$data` in this case). Despite the similarity of syntax, that's not a shell interpolation; we're passing the literal text `$data` to `jq`, and `jq` itself is what replaces it with the value of the variable (which was passed as the second argument to `--arg`).

There's another tool called `jo`, which doesn't manipulate JSON but rather produces it, from input that is easier to generate in the shell. Here's one way to construct the desired object with it:

```
jo name=my-project files="$(jo -a "$(jo data="$stringVar")")"
```

Either way you can include the constructed JSON in your `curl` command line like this:

```
curl ... -d "$(jo or jq command goes here)"
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for your well thought out answers. I was able to get my request submitted successfully. For my particular implementation (which was slightly different that the example I used in the question), I was able to get it working with @Mark Reed's answer and jq. Much appreciated!

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote it and accept it (via the checkmark)!

Answer (score 1):

Do not generate such JSON by hand. Use a tool like `jq` to do it for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

stringVar="helloWorldFunction() {\n echo \"hello world\" \n}"

jq -n --arg s "$stringVar" '{name: "my-project", files: [{data: $s}]}' |
  curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_API_TOKEN>" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
          -H "Accept: application/json" \
          -X POST  \
          -d @- \
          'https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

stringVar="..."

curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_API_TOKEN>" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST 'https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint' \
    -d@/dev/stdin <<EOF
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "files": [
        {
            "data": $stringVar
        },
    ],
}
EOF
```

You then should take care about what you fed in the variable, this have to be valid `JSON`

Comment: Will break JSON syntax when `$stringVar` contains double quotes or non-printable characters like newlines, line-feed...

Comment: OP need to take care about what it put inside the variable

Comment: On ne peut pas mettre de string dans l'array =)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `jq` *and* `curl` you could use [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) to generate the JSON *and* submit the POST-request.

With command-line options:

```
#!/bin/bash

stringVar='helloWorldFunction() {\n echo "hello world" \n}'

xidel -s --variable var="$stringVar" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY_API_TOKEN>" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Accept: application/json"
  -d '{serialize(
    {"name":"my-project","files":array{{"data":$var}}},
    {"method":"json"}
  )}' \
  "https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint" \
  -e '$raw'
```

Or with the [`x:request()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-request) function in-query:

```
#!/bin/bash

stringVar='helloWorldFunction() {\n echo "hello world" \n}'

xidel -s --variable var="$stringVar" -e '
  x:request({
    "headers":(
      "Authorization: Bearer <MY_API_TOKEN>",
      "Content-Type: application/json",
      "Accept: application/json"
    ),
    "post":serialize(
      {"name":"my-project","files":array{{"data":$var}}},
      {"method":"json"}
    ),
    "url":"https://api.example.com/v1/endpoint"
  })/raw
'
```

`$raw` / `/raw` returns the raw output, like `curl`. If the API-endpoint returns JSON, then you can use `$json` / `/json` to parse it.